# Calling a class from one jinternalframe to another

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jinternalframe

I have two jinternalframe in a java project JF1 and JF2.

I have created a class named as insert_in_JF1, now I want to call this class from JF2 by passing some parameters.

Is this possible?

JF1 like this where Insert is a class and InsertValues() is a method now i want to call this method from JF2

```
public class Insert extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {                                            
   public void InsertValues()
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Working");
   } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is not quiet clear. "I have created a class named as insert in JF1".  is `insert` a method  ? a nested class ? a static class ? . [mcve] would be best

Comment: JF1 like this where Insert is a class and InsertValues() is a method now i want to call this method from JF2



public class Insert extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {                                            
    public void InsertValues()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Working");
    } 
}

Comment: Sorry it does not help me understand. It did not answer all my questions and does not include [mcve]